# Kentico GetUserDataFromAuthCookie() returning null

Tags: c#, kentico

I'm working on the sample K10 corporate site. 
On SignOutButton.ascx.cs I moved the call to `GetUserDataFromAuthCookie()` so the breakpoint would always hit like so:

```
if (AuthenticationHelper.IsAuthenticated())
{
    string[] userData = AuthenticationHelper.GetUserDataFromAuthCookie();
}
```

I'm sure the browser is storing the cookies because when I use the stay logged in option, I stay logged in. However, `GetUserDataFromAuthCookie()` always returns null.

Does this only work when the user is authenticated with WindowsLiveID?

Cheers,

Rory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at [the source code of SignOutButton.ascx.cs](https://github.com/KuduApps/Kentico/blob/master/CMSWebParts/Membership/Logon/SignOutButton.ascx.cs) userdata available only inside condition  `if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(CMSContext.CurrentUser.UserSettings.WindowsLiveID))`.  The helper just calls standard asp.net method inside to get [userdata property from forms authentication ticket](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthenticationticket.userdata(v=vs.110).aspx), unless you've saved something yourself inside the [authentication ticket userdata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-security/introduction/forms-authentication-configuration-and-advanced-topics-vb#step-4-storing-additional-user-data-in-the-ticket) - there is nothing to get.  I would assume when WindowsLiveID is in use, some info is saved in the userdata. All other times it is just empty. UserData  is a useful place to put small amounts of information about the user that is commonly needed. Unless you put somehting yourself there, it is empty.